# Build agent keep failing with error ERR:self signed certificate in certificate chain

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-build-task

My build keeps failing and getting the error ERR:self signed certificate in certificate chain
I've tried fixing is with this post 
https://mehmetkut.com/2018/05/vsts-agent-self-signed-certificate-fix-en/

but that didn't work.  I also tried to see if i could turn off the ssl
removing agent and then reconfiguring it using the command

.\config.cmd --sslskipcertvalidation but this didnt do anything and just took
me to the simple set up with PAT

Am I missing something here, and help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does the issue still happen now? You can try to whitelist the build server from the security agent

Comment: Hi @HughLin-MSFT how do i locate the security agent to whitelist the build server? Can you give me some steps where it would be.

Comment: welcome to the enterprise-proxy world